# Format specific section of String

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I have a `String`: `a%sb%sc%s`. I need to format `b` before I format `a` or `c`, but I'm not sure how or even if I can specify only to format `b` while keeping the rest of the `String` unformatted.

In other words, I'm trying to do this:

```
String.format(foo, "test");
```

With the outcome:

```
a%sbtestc%s
```

Is it possible to manipulate a `String` like this or should I just use `String.replace` instead?

A little more detail. The ultimate `String` will look something like: `aA-PARMbB-PARMcC-PARM` and then used to fetch some data. `a` and `c` are much more dynamic than `b`, so I'm trying to format `b` before hand.

So, again. I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
String.format(foo, "B-PARM");
```

With the results:

```
a%sbB-PARMc%s
```

Then format the rest:

```
String.format(formattedFoo, "A-PARM", "C-PARM");
```

Comment: What are the criteron that separate a from b from c?

Comment: @Emrakul Various parameters for an API.

Comment: This question smells like a possible [xy problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. Can you post more details on the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than your proposed code solution since their very well may be a better way to approach this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your formatting in steps,

```
String aString = String.format("something %s something else", "a string");
String bString = String.format("...%s...", "test");
String cString = // ....

String completeString = String.format("a%sb%sc%s", aString, bString, cString);
```

but again, I have to wonder what is going on, and whether this represents an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), one that is best solved by a completely different approach. Consider giving us the details of the overall problem that you're trying to solve and perhaps not the code tactics that you're using to try to solve it.